# How do I make the soft keyboard push not directly to the Edit Text, but to a specific place below the Edit Text? (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml

Here is an example of what's happening currently:

[image]

On the left (before the keyboard comes up), there is the black bar of the Edit Text, and then some padding below that. On the right, you can see the keyboard pushes up all the way to the Edit Text, and overlays that padding.

How can I make it so the keyboard pushes up to the point below the padding? The current situation looks too crowded, so I want to preserve that extra space.

Comment: U dont want that large white space on the left ? Paste your code of xml!

Comment: That blank space is not in the phone's screenshot. That's just the background of Paint where I pasted these images in. I'll edit the picture so it's more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is setting the soft input state to adjustResize, in AndroidManifest add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

to the Activity.

Since I have a bunch of frags within that Activity that each need different states, I used

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

or

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

to programmatically change the state depending on the frag.